# VBA Copy formula from first empty row till end of data

Tags: excel, copy, formula, vba

Can you help me to solve this with macro?
There are data in column A, but the amount of the filled cells are changing week by week.
There are data in column B but the number of filled cells are always less than in column A, and number of the cells are also changing.
I need a code which:
1) finds the first empty cell of column B;
2) adds a formula to that cell;
3) copies down the formula till the last row of column A.

E.g:
Column A is filled from A1 to A100. Column B filled from B1 to B50. The macro shall find the cell B51, add the formula and copy down the formula till B100.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not just keep the formulas in the cells all the time, adding an `IF` statement to display nothing (`""`) when the data isn't present in that row?

Answer (score 0):

May be (if you like to use a macro)

```
Sub Test()
Dim lrA As Long
Dim lrB As Long

lrA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lrB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Range("B" & lrB).Resize(lrA - lrB + 1).Formula = "=Today()"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks YasserKhalil, it started great but runs to error. My formula is a simple "=Today ()" , btw.

Comment: You're welcome. I tried that on sample data and it works fine for me